# Solve the trigonometric equation: $\cos (3x)-\sin(x)=\sqrt 3(\cos (x)-\sin(3x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

Solve the trigonometric equation:

> $$\cos (3x)-\sin(x)=\sqrt 3(\cos (x)-\sin(3x))$$

My answer is contradictory to Wolfram Alpha.

Because, W.A. gives me:

> $x = \pi n - \frac {11 \pi}{12},   n \in \mathbb{ Z}$
>
> $x = \pi n - \frac {7 \pi}{12},   n \in \mathbb{ Z}$
>
> $x = \pi n - \frac {3 \pi}{12},   n \in \mathbb{ Z}$

But, my answer is:

> $x=\frac {\pi}{12}+\pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$
>
> $x=\frac {\pi}{8}+\frac {\pi k}{2}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$

*Is my solution wrong? Or What is the problem in my solution?*

Comment: Please share your answer

Comment: I fixed, Please see now..

Comment: $$\dfrac\pi{12}+\pi k=\pi n-\dfrac{11\pi}{12}$$

$$\iff k=n-1$$

Comment: Hmmm..I understood). But, WA gives me 3 answer, but I have 2 answer..

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=27b8624af4f632acc36d65c4a7eb715

Comment: I am sorry, english is my second language. I looked Your WA link. $\sin x=\cos( \pi /2)$ but  I do not understood what you mean. Finally, You say that my solution is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73420/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-math).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac\pi{12}+\pi k=\pi n-\dfrac{11\pi}{12}$$

$$\iff k=n-1$$

Now for odd $k,k=2m+1$(say)

$\dfrac\pi8+\dfrac{\pi k}2=\dfrac\pi8+\dfrac{\pi(2m+1)}2=m\pi+\dfrac{5\pi}8=(m+1)\pi-\dfrac{3\pi}8$

For even $k,k=2m$(say), $\dfrac\pi8+\dfrac{\pi k}2=m\pi+\dfrac\pi8=(m+1)\pi-\dfrac{7\pi}8$

So, there must be mistake in the W.A. unless there is some typo in your [input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=27b8624af4f632acc36d65c4a7eb715)

Comment: I understood. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\cos (3x)-\sin(x)}{\cos (x)-\sin(3x)}=\sqrt 3$$
$$\frac{\sin (\pi/2-3x)-\sin(x)}{\sin (\pi/2-x)-\sin(3x)}=\sqrt 3$$
$$\frac{2\cos(\pi/4-x)\sin(\pi/4-2x)}{2\cos(\pi/4+x)\sin(\pi/4-2x)}=\sqrt 3$$
$$\frac{\cos(\pi/4-x)}{\cos(\pi/4+x)}=\sqrt 3$$
$$\frac{\sin(\pi/2-\pi/4+x)}{\cos(\pi/4+x)}=\sqrt 3$$
$$\tan(\pi/4+x)=\tan(\pi/3)$$
then
$$\pi/4+x=k\pi+\pi/3$$
or
$$x=k\pi+\pi/12$$

Comment: Did you consider the case where $\sin(\frac\pi4-2x)=0$?